# How to render custom yAxis label on Highcharts Gantt with the 'custom' property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I've got a Gantt chart:

[image]

And I want to use the [series.gantt.custom](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.custom) object to set specific properties for each series on the yAxis.

From these properties I want to construct the yAxis labels.

My code:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

  yAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2'],
    labels: {
      formatter() {
       return this.value  
        /*  + this.chart.series[this.pos].custom.size */
      },
    }
  },
  series: [{
    groupPadding: 1,
    custom: {
      size: "small",
    },
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
      custom: {
        label: 1,
      }
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
      custom: {
        label: 2
      }
    }]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    custom: {
      size: "large",
    },
    data: [{
      y: 1,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 18),
      custom: {
        label: 1
      }
    }, {
      y: 1,
      x: Date.UTC(2022, 10, 25, 12),
      custom: {
        label: 2
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

`this.chart.series[this.pos].custom.size` it's the bit that is not working.

The labels should be `1 small` and `2 large`.

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fmcg/czx0une2/27/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach this property through the `series.options`:

```
this.chart.series[this.pos].options.custom.size
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gLkn9uqf/

Comment: Spot on. I was missing the `options.`. thanks a lot